# Inject variables into closure

Tags: php, javascript, closures

What would be the proper way to achieve something like this, without binding it to the window object?

```
x = function(fn)
{
    foo = 'bar';
    fn();
}

x(function()
{
    console.log(foo) // error happens here
});
```

In PHP you can do trough the "use" directive.

```
$foo = 'bar';
$fn = function() use($foo)
{
    echo $foo; // bar
}
```

Edit: I changed the piece of code a bit. What I'm trying to achieve is, to make a declared variable available in a closure, without the need to pass it there.

```
foo = 'bar';
console.log(foo) // bar
console.log(window.foo) // bar
console.log(this.foo) // bar
```

I want to achieve the same effect, with another object that has been bound as "this".

Comment: I don't get what you want. I just hope the answer isn't `with`.

Comment: What do you mean with `without binding it to the window object` ? When you make a closure you make a kind of bound to the enclosing scope.

Comment: That shouldn't say `undefined`. Works fine here http://jsbin.com/evacak/1/edit

Comment: this works ... I get 'bar' and 'foo' in console

Comment: I actually think the answer is eval + a bunch of custom logic. In other words, what you're trying to do isn't inherently possible afaik, though you are wrong that `console.log(foo)` would provide `undefined` as proven: http://jsfiddle.net/tBDWJ/

Comment: I made another example.

Comment: Your new code still works (even if adding `var` would be cleaner)...

Comment: You should probably close this mess and make a new question once you got what is really bothering you.

Comment: and if you add `;` semicolons at and of all expressions, would be better ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm gonna open a new question with a clean example.

Comment: Check before that florian didn't in fact understand your problem.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense

Comment: Why did you tagged your question as `php` & `javascript` at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, guess what, JavaScript has **real** closures. Not half-baked ones like PHP has, where you have to manually declare all the variables in the closure you want to use.

The equivalent of this PHP code:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$fn = function() use($foo)
{
    echo $foo; // bar
}
```

Is this in JS:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var fn = function() {
    console.log(foo);
};
```

Yep. You're not calling your function in PHP, why would I call it in the JS example? :-)

By the way, if you run this bit of code in your JS console:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var fn = function() {
    console.log(foo);
};
fn();
```

You will see "bar" logged. Proof that closures work without needing some hack. (`use`)

Regarding global variables: the `$foo` variable is global in your PHP example. They are in the JS example too. If you want to have a not-global variable, you need a local environment. Most of the times, a function.

PHP example with not-global variables:

```
function baz() {
    $foo = 'bar';
    $fn = function() use ($foo) {
        echo $foo;
    };
}
```

JS example with not-global variables:

```
function baz() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    var fn = function() {
        console.log(foo);
    };
}
```

**One last note**: if you don't use `var` to declare new variables in JS, they are *implied globals*. In the browser, it means they are attached on the `window` object.

If you want a PHP/JS comparison of how to declare global variables:

PHP code:

```
$foo; // global
function bar() {
    $_GLOBAL['baz']; // global
    $bin; // local
}
```

JS code:

```
foo; // global
function bar() {
    window.baz; // global
    var bin; // local
    booze; // implied global
}
```

Comment: You're using the same scope. That's why it works in your example. If you would pass the fn a several times trough other functions this wouldn't work anymore. But my example was really bad, so it's OK. Thank You!

Comment: Having to declare the variables captured does not make it any less of a closure.

Comment: Agree, it could be even seen as beneficial in some cases (implicit vs explicit)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your window object clean then this may be what you need.

```
(function(){

  var foo = 'bar';

  (function(){
      console.log(foo) // bar
  })();

})();

console.log(window.foo); //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in PHP you select what gets enclosed. In JS, there is no way to tell a closure to pick which variables to enclose. All lexically available variables are enclosed.

But it's hard to tell what you want, it looks like you want to hide a closure variable

The only workaround is to shadow the variables (by declaring them in the inner function) you don't want

Comment: That's what I've thought :(

Comment: I wonder if the OP wants `.call()` to determine the value of `this` within a function, (which is not necessarily a closure issue)?

Comment: Wait, what? Why do you want to shadow the closure's variables? It's the first time I've heard such a hack (`use`) mentioned as a feature :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it saves memory, note that Chrome does closure optimization and only encloses what's actually used, unless you have an eval in there. And I don't want to shadow anything, just trying to make sense of a poorly asked question

Comment: Shadowing variables in order to save memory ? That's a first for me... And the second sentence seems to negate the first one.

Comment: @dystroy I did not say shadow variables to save memory.  I was trying to figure out what the OP is trying to do. I said requiring uses makes the compiler know what it will need. In JS, the optimization routine has to guess, but can't if you have an eval in there. Read Florian's comment and you'll see that shadowing is my guess as to what the OP wants, and memory savings is what `uses` gives you without the compiler having to do guesswork

Comment: note that you should never use `eval`. Even `new Function` fares better just for the very reason it doesn't see the local scope (but you should reconsider your design if you feel the need to use either)

Answer (score 0):

In the latter part of your question you ask about calling
a function with `this` set to a specified object.

To call function `fun` setting `this` to `objectThatBecomesThis` and also setting the arguments to (arg1,arg2,...)  use:

```
fun.apply(objectThatBecomesThis, [arg1,arg2,...])
```

where the 2nd parameter (optional) is an array of arguments for the function.

Because the 2nd parameter is an array, it uses [] square brackets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your need, you can do that:

```
var closure_variables = new Object();;
closure_variables.foo = 'bar';
window.bar = 'foo'

(function(variables)
{
    console.log(variables.foo) // undefined
    console.log(bar) // foo
})(closure_variables)
```

Or you can even pass directly foo in the arguments.

Comment: You make the same error than the other similar (identical?) answer.

Comment: i'll offer up a duplicate comment ..  this would also require `(function (closure_variables)`